# Angular: ngModel Error because I am using an array

Tags: angular

I have the next issue in **angular**:

I have this **json** as **entity**:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "I am ok"
}
```

I have my own model as **json** like :

```
[{
   "Field": "id",
   "ReadOnly": true,
   "BackColor": "silver",
   "Type": "Text"
},{
   "Field": "value",
   "ReadOnly": true,
   "BackColor": "silver",
   "Type": "Text"
}]
```

Once I get the correct information in the subscription (first json I showed you), I am making, in the template of the component, a loop of model to configure the dialog and I am using **matInput** to show the values.

Ok I am trying to build something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let col of row.data" class="col-{{col.ColType}}-{{col.Col}}"  [ngSwitch]="col.Type" style="width: 100% !important">

</div>
```

row.data is each col of the model converted to array.

Inside div I am making something like:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let data of classe.Data"> 
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data[col.Field.toLowerCase()]" [name]="col.Field.toLowerCase()" >
</mat-form-field>
```

classe.Data is the class of first **json** I wrote.

I am getting the next error:

***core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.***

Do I have other way to avoid this error? I would like to use ngModel but if not possible I am open to use other way.

Thx

Comment: Are you trying to show just 2 input boxes? one for the `id` and one for the `value`?

Answer (score 1):

try out angular's KeyValuePipe (https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe). It transforms objects or maps into an array of key value pairs which you can use with ngFor if you don't have an array.

Here is an example how to iterate properties of an array, map and object.

**Component:**

```
...
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  arr:string[] =["foo", "bar"];
  map = new Map([[2, 'foo'], [1, 'bar']]);
  object: {[key: number]: string} = {2: 'foo', 1: 'bar'};
}
```

**Template:**

```html
<h2>Iterate array</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let item of arr | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>

<h2>Iterate through a map</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let item of map | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>

<h2>Iterate over object properties</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
```

**Output:**

```
Iterate array
0:foo
1:bar

Iterate through a map
1:bar
2:foo

Iterate over object properties
1:bar
2:foo
```

**Stackblitz:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gf7yas

If you remove the keyvalue-pipe from the last two examples, so you try to iterate over an object and a map, you will get the error:

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
>   type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23990562)

Comment: @MihaiChelaru thanks, i added the keyfact to my answer. Did you vote down because of this?

Comment: I did not. The review interface does not allow downvotes. I simply react to the post as I see it. It might have been the person who originally flagged the answer. If I had, I would retract it upon seeing you've edited your post to take the review feedback into account. You should delete your other answer asking for clarification from the user, as it should really be a comment. Answers are for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru ok, i deleted the other answer

Comment: This wasn't actually a deletable link-only-answer even before the edit, as, stripping the markup from that version, you get "try out the KeyValuePipe. Here is an example how to iterate properties of an array, map and object.", which is still an (admittedly low-quality) attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your final template is but I don't think you even need the second `ngFor`. With two `ngFor`, you will end up getting four inputs in total while you only have two parameters. I'm guessing you just need two inputs, one for the `id` and one for the `value`.

Try this if that is your requirement

```js
<div *ngFor="let col of row.data" class="col-{{col.ColType}}-{{col.Col}}" [ngSwitch]="col.Type" style="width: 100% !important">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="classe.Data[col.Field.toLowerCase()]" [name]="col.Field.toLowerCase()" >
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: yes I am agree with you. I tested with ngFor but it is not working, anyway I got to bind using events, now I write one possible solution

Comment: But the code above will bind your data directly without the need for any events since the `ngModel` will directly modify the values in `classe.Data`. So any change in your input will directly modify your JSON. I can provide a sample code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

A good way I found is using events:

In the component I wrote:

```
onKey = (field: string, ev) => {
    this.classe.Data[field.toLowerCase()] = ev.target.value;
}
```

and template will be:

```
<mat-form-field> 
    <mat-label>{{col.Translate | translate}}</mat-label>                                              
    <input matInput 
        (keyup)="onKey(col.Field.toLowerCase(), $event)" 
        [name]="col.Field.toLowerCase()" 
        [value]="classe.Data[col.Field.toLowerCase()]">
</mat-form-field>
```

It is one solution for me. I would love to use ngModel but ...